# What gets imported from '@salesforce/user/isGuest'?

Tags: lightning-web-components, user, lightning-community, import

`import isguest from '@salesforce/user/isGuest';` What does this line mean? I don't see any user **isGuest** created in org. Where can I look to find isGuest in org?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is used to

> check whether or not the user is authenticated in the Experience Builder site.

This is a property on `User` object, but not sure if you can query it in SOQL.

More info on : [Guest User Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.get_current_user)

Comment: FYI, you will be able to call a method to determine guest status: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Auth_CommunitiesUtil.htm ... `Auth.CommunitiesUtil.isGuestUser()` returns true if a guest.